# Protractor: getText doesn't get value of input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I just wanted to point out that if you have something like this:

```
element(by.model('someModel')).sendKeys('some value');
expect(by.model('someModel').getText()).toMatch('some value');
```

will **fail**!

Comment: What is "someModel"? getText() works for me. But probably doesn't work in inputs.

Have you tried this?

expect(element(by.css('input[name="something"]')).getAttribute('value')).toMatch('some value');

Comment: `someModel` is the value of an element's `ng-model` angular attribute. Regarding the latter part of your comment - see the solution I provided below.

Comment: when working with inputs don't use get text use getAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `getText()` will return an empty string - no matter what!

Instead, you should use:

```
expect(element(by.model('someModel')).getAttribute('value')).toMatch('some value');
```